# How to change background-color with this element type?

Tags: javascript

I am getting via ajax from a JSON response from a Microsoft Recognition Services API. I receive and enter the received data correctly in the HTML.

But I would like to do the following:
He is going through the "Face" Array that contains the sex information of the person, the condition is as follows:

If it's a man, add background-color blue and if it's a woman add background-color pink, and it can come in information at the same time man and woman.

I can only add one color, I can not add more than one color at a time.

**CODE [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8EUHo.png):**

```
var iconSexColor = document.getElementsByClassName('icon-sex-color');

function CheckSex__(objJSON){
  for(fac in objJSON.faces){
    console.log(objJSON.faces[fac].gender);
    if(objJSON.faces[fac].gender === "Male"){
      //console.log("M:");
      InsertColorSex__("Male");
    } else if(objJSON.faces[fac].gender === "Female"){
      //console.log("F");
      InsertColorSex__("Female");
    } else{
      // TODO
    }
  }
}

function InsertColorSex__(typeSex){
  console.log("t:", typeSex);
  if(typeSex === "Male"){
    console.log("OI: M");
    for(var count = 0; count < iconSexColor.length; count++){
      iconSexColor[count].style.backgroundColor = "blue";
    }
  } else if(typeSex === "Female"){
    console.log("OI: F");
    for(var count = 0; count < iconSexColor.length; count++){
      iconSexColor[count].style.backgroundColor = "pink";
    }
  } else{
    // TODO
  }

}
```

CODE [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xqMKh.png):

```
      .done(function(data){
        // Transforma o JSON(DATA) Recebido em Objeto.
        var objJSON = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data, null, 2));
        console.log(objJSON);
        GeneratePeoples__(objJSON);
        GenerateCaptions__(objJSON);
        GenerateCelebrities__(objJSON);
        CheckSex__(objJSON);

      })

 function GenerateCelebrities__(objJSON){
  for(cat in objJSON.categories){
    for(cel in objJSON.categories[cat].detail.celebrities){
      document.getElementById('celebrities-information').innerHTML +=
      '<ul class="collapsible" data-collapsible="accordion">' +
        '<li>' +
          '<div class="collapsible-header"><i class="fa fa-id-card-o" aria-hidden="true"></i><strong>Celebrity ('+ cap++ +')</strong></div>' +
          '<div class="collapsible-body white">' +
            '<ul class="collection">' +
              '<li class="collection-item avatar">' +
                '<i class="icon-sex-color fa fa-star circle yellow-text" aria-hidden="true"></i>' +
                '<span class="title title-collection-content-information">Celebrity Name</span>' +
                '<p><strong>'+ objJSON.categories[cat].detail.celebrities[cel].name +'</strong></p>' +
                '<a href="#!" class="secondary-content">' +
                  '<span class="new black badge" data-badge-caption=" "><strong>'+ objJSON.categories[cat].detail.celebrities[cel].confidence +" %" +'</strong></span>' +
                  '<span class="new black badge" data-badge-caption=" "><strong>Confidence</strong></span>' +
                '</a>' +
              '</li>' +
            '</ul>' +
          '</div>' +
        '</li>' +
      '</ul>';
    }
  }
  InicializarCollapsible__();
};
```

**INSERT COLOR HERE:**

```
'<i class="fa fa-star circle yellow-text '+ InsertColorSex__() +'" aria-hidden="true"></i>' +
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: can you share what fac and cat array looks like

Comment: @AnilShrestha Yes. I changed now.

Comment: i mean the console values fac and cat

Comment: @AnilShrestha I'm sorry, look now.

Answer (score 0):

`InsertColorSex__()` is writting something in the css classes of the element so it could add a class that changes background-color css property.

Another thing is your `CheckSex__(objJSON)` function, that tries to loop over the results but return the firs occurence for the gender if Male or Female. But supposing it is working correctly, as you show in the console log, you could use that function to add pink or blue class to he element as you are passing `objJSON` to the function `GenerateCelebrities__ building` the HTML.

```
'<i class="fa fa-star circle yellow-text '+ CheckSex__(objJSON) +'" aria-hidden="true"></i>'
```

So after adding that you should declare the CSS rule in your CSS Stylesheet.

```
.pink { background-color: pink; }
.blue { background-color: blue; }
```

Comment: I added a new code to the answer. It adds color, however it just adds a color that is pink. Can you tell me why this happens and how to arrange for it to add color separately?

Comment: Oh man. This is getting more complicated as you add code. The other solution proposed will work https://stackoverflow.com/a/45820053/4635829 better and simpler than looping again and again your data in the objJSON object.

Answer (score 0):

i still cant figure out your console but what you should do is before generating html you should add color property in in your category array object by checking gender. there should be some id or value that lets you to know that which face gender is of which category(i mean celeberaty)

for example

```
    for(cat in objJSON.categories){
        for(cel in objJSON.categories[cat].detail.celebrities){
            for(fac in objJSON.faces){
                if(objJSON.faces[fac].celebrity_id == objJSON.categories[cat].detail.celebrities[cel].celebrity_id){

                    if(objJSON.faces[fac].gender === "Male"){
                      objJSON.categories[cat].detail.celebrities[cel].color = "blue";     
                    } else if(objJSON.faces[fac].gender === "Female") {
                      objJSON.categories[cat].detail.celebrities[cel].color = "pink";

                    } else {
                      objJSON.categories[cat].detail.celebrities[cel].color = "green";
                    }

                }

            }
        }
    }
```

Now you can print your color value in

```
'<i class="fa fa-star circle yellow-text" style="color:'+  objJSON.categories[cat].detail.celebrities[cel].color+'" aria-hidden="true"></i>' +
```

there may be some mistakes in referring object property in loop. Hope this gives you some ideas.

Answer (score 0):

**The solution is this:**

```
function CheckSex__(objJSON) {
  for (fac in objJSON.faces) {
    if (objJSON.faces[fac].gender === "Male") {
      $('#icon-sex-color'+ fac).css("background-color", "#1565c0");
    } else if (objJSON.faces[fac].gender === "Female") {
      $('#icon-sex-color'+ fac).css("background-color", "#e91e63");
    } else {
      // TODO
    }
  }
}
```